# Why Shall i use a PHP Framework

Tags: php, frameworks

I m New to WEB Development I use Apache2.0i and NOTEPAD++ for web development i came to hear about some new words CAKEPHP, CodeINgniter Zend Etc.

Can any one please Tell me in detail why do i need Frameworks what is the benefit of these frameworks i dont really understand these frameworks.

Comment: Please read [this part of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). This question is too open-ended to be a good fit for Stack Overflow - questions here should boil down to being [practical and uniformly answerable](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://bit.ly/12J5kHz).

Comment: this is indeed not a good quesiton..however, I've answered bellow..next time, google is your friend, here you come with problems you have with code, or complex design problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just **never find a good example** of raw PHP code over the whole internet.
So, learning raw PHP you will learn ancient techniques and bad practices as well.

While framework tutorials will teach you a better ways, good practices and safer code.

Comment: unless you're a good programmer..there is a very long debate for and aginast frameworks in php ...

Comment: @DoryZidon "While framework tutorials will teach you a better ways, good practices and safer code."

Comment: @Khan yes I am ok with reading..still, I frameworks also hide the way php works, which isn't great...personally I'd rather you understand how php works, only then do framework...

Answer (score 3):

Despite this question is very unwelcomed in this community.  I would like to point you http://www.phpframeworks.com/‎

And please focus on core PHP if you are starting on PHP Development, it will make you much stronger.

Answer (score 1):

There are many considerations for and against using frameworks.

Frameworks provide you with a given structure and idioms which should help you yield a better app with a well defined structure.

Furthermore frameworks many time give you shortcuts to make things easier and more customize-able such as build in template engine, mvc and more.

[Ten Reasons to use a Framework](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/top-10-reasons-why-you-should-use-a-php-framework)

Answer (score 1):

As a new developer you can start with any framework. Frameworks make the life of the developer easier, read : [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)

Just focus on one framework and learn as much as you can. Once you have a good understanding of web dev, you can choose the framework which suits your style/requirements.